# Assigning labels to HOG features for training an SVM classifier

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, svm

```
import cv2
image = cv2.imread("cat.1.jpg",0)
winSize = (64,64)
blockSize = (16,16)
blockStride = (8,8)
cellSize = (8,8)
nbins = 9
derivAperture = 1
winSigma = 4.
histogramNormType = 0
L2HysThreshold = 2.0000000000000001e-01
gammaCorrection = 0
nlevels = 64
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor(winSize,blockSize,blockStride,cellSize,nbins,derivAperture,winSigma,histogramNormType,L2HysThreshold,gammaCorrection,nlevels)
winStride = (8,8)
padding = (8,8)
locations = ((10,20),)
hist = hog.compute(image,winStride,padding,locations)
print (hist)
print (len(hist))
print (len(hist[0]))
```

I have nearly 50000 images of dogs(25K) and cats(25K).I want to train an SVM classifier so that it correctly predicts whether a particular image is of dog or cat.By using the HOG descriptor I am getting the feature vector of size 1764*1 of a particular image.

How can I use the feature vectors of all the images?And also how can I provide the labels(e.g. 1 for cat or -1 for dog).Note the image filename  is of format  at.1.jpg,cat.2.jpg.............cat.25000.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
winSize = (64,64)
blockSize = (16,16)
blockStride = (8,8)
cellSize = (8,8)
nbins = 9
derivAperture = 1
winSigma = 4.
histogramNormType = 0
L2HysThreshold = 2.0000000000000001e-01
gammaCorrection = 0
nlevels = 64
hog = cv2.HOGDescriptor(winSize,blockSize,blockStride,cellSize,nbins,derivAperture,winSigma,histogramNormType,L2HysThreshold,gammaCorrection,nlevels)
#compute(img[, winStride[, padding[, locations]]]) -> descriptors
winStride = (8,8)
padding = (8,8)
locations = ((10,20),)
out = []
for x in range(0,12500):
    image = cv2.imread("cat or dog.{}.jpg".format(x),0)
    hist = hog.compute(image,winStride,padding,locations))
    out.append(hist)
np.savetxt("hog.txt",out)
```

Next after each hog features you can assign labels on your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html

The syntax for the SVM is slightly different, like to train it becomes svm->train(training_mat, ROW_SAMPLE, labels_mat)

Labels correctly are assigned using 1 for a positive sample and -1 for a negative sample. These labels are then fed into a labels_mat and then used for the SVM training procedure